# I have to add java code in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, xss, cross-site

I have a javascript file **script.js**, which has the following code

```
var winLoc = String(this.window.location);
var pos = winLoc.indexOf("lang=");
var spacer = '?';
if(pos >0) {
    var curLang = winLoc.substring(pos+5,pos+7);
    winLoc = winLoc.replace('lang=' + curLang, 'lang='+newLang);

} else {
    if(winLoc.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        spacer = '&';
    }

    winLoc = winLoc + spacer + 'lang=' + newLang;
}

this.window.location = winLoc;  //cross site scripting issue//
```

I have to add this java code for the variable winLoc

```
winLoc = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(winLoc);
```

and this encoder() method is in **ESAPI jar** which I need to add as well

I am using it to avoid XSS Cross-Site Scripting Reflected.

Help me out in adding this java code to the JS file or any alternative you have in mind?

Comment: `java` in the browser? Is that still something that actually happens?

Comment: i know it is not possible to add java code on the client side. I asked for any alternative for this.

Comment: You already included JSP as a tag, what is you knowledge about JSP? You can do things like passing variables with JSP. Another way of passing variables from back-end to front-end would be a template engine e.g. thymeleaf or mustache

Comment: Do you HAVE TO include the ESAPI check? I think you should be able to do all of this client-side via JS. As long as you're in control of that code, I suppose. Identify which are the untrusted arguments and HTML encode them. If neither `winLoc`, nor `spacer`, nor `newLang` could be controlled by a user, then the sanitization is superfluous at best. Although I'm not really sure *why* you'd want to do that for the URL. Surely any HTML code in the URL would already be URL encoded. If you're reading the URL and blindly putting it in `.innerHTML` or something, THAT is the problem.

Comment: @vlaz, will you please show me a small code sample which will help me do this at client side JS? and yes, I am in the control of the code.

Comment: It's actually dead simple: 1. create any HTML element `parser = document.createElement('div')` I prefer divs but pretty much anything works. 2. Now set your input as text `parser.textContent = input` 3. get it back `safeInput = parser.innerHTML`. This offloads all of this to the browser - any HTML would be escaped because the browser will make sure it's going to be shown as text, rather than parsed as HTML - `"<br/>"` -> `"&lt;br/&gt;"`.

Comment: thanks vlaz, but I am not displaying this data. The issue is coming at this line "this.window.location = winLoc;" in .js file. have any advice on this ?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't really matter if you're displaying it or not - using an in-memory element to parse and escape the value, you're left with a sanitized HTML that will not be read as HTML any more. That's what `encodeForHTML` would also be doing. The data is then put back in the *URL* even though it's now safe for *HTML*. As I said, I'm not really sure why that is but it fits the requirement you've put forward without involving Java.

Comment: In reality, I'm not sure what that is protecting from - the only threat vector is if the *current* URL contains HTML and you then blindly grab that and place it somewhere in the DOM. Say, you grab the URL and make a link out of it contains some `<script>` tag that injects malicious content. I'd expect such a URL lead nowhere, thus no page would be displayed. So the only suspects are `spacer`, which I would guess can either be `?` or `&` and not controlled by the user and `newLang` that might be user controlled *somehow*. Although, it really shouldn't be.

Comment: @vlaz I have pasted the exact code in the question. please give it a look.

Comment: The whole strategy seems...odd, honestly. The real problem I see is `newLang` since a malicious user can just send a link to a victim: `domain.com?lang=<script src='badscript.js'></script>` however, this code will not protect against this case. Not necessarily - it seems to only be concerned with *appending* the `lang` parameter to the query string, I would guess it doesn't run if it's present so a link would still be dangerous. And, really, you should be sanitizing after grabbing the URL anyway, instead of sanitizing and redirecting. Also, if the URL contains `&` it'd be turned into `&amp;`

Comment: @vlaz, what would you have done for removing cross site scripting if you were in my shoes? will you advice me with small code sample to help me sanitize/validate/encrypt/anything the winLoc variable?

Comment: I am not sure what I'd do. The problem is that I don't know what is the threat vector you need to protect from. If neither the URL, nor `spacer`, nor `newLoc` are controlled by the user OR the URL isn't blindly taken and placed inside the DOM, then there is no actual threat. If the URL is vulnerable in any way but parsed any time when placed in the DOM, then there is no XSS problem. If the attacker can manipulate only `newLang`, only sanitize that. Without knowledge, I'd probably elect to have a helper function for fetching the URL that does parsing and use that any time I need to get the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont know what are you intending to get done, but generally, you cant execute Java code inside JavaScript.

Javascript is client side, meaning its interpreted by users browser, while Java is compiled into bytecode and executed by JVM on server side.

However, you can run JSP in a  element, but it has to return valid JS.

> https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-expression-tag

Comment: `while Java is compiled into bytecode and executed by JVM on server side.` yet there are also appliets which Java was initially heavily into. Not suggesting an applet be used here but just pointing it out as the statement "Java only works on the server" tends to show up a lot.

Comment: @vlaz correct, 'JSP is compiled...' would be more exact

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to use a JavaScript based tool in stead. Look at something like DOMPurify or jquery encoder.

For the specific context you are asking, HTML escaping looks wrong. You probably use encodeURIComponent instead.

Comment: if I use encodeURIComponent(winloc) then do I need to decode it later for usage?